# How to run client and server side code for same button?

Tags: asp.net

In Asp.NET aspx page, there is a button for data Save, when user click on this button, I want:
1. Disable this button immediately
2. Then call code behind function Save() to save data back to DB
3. Then enable this button again.

What I did as below:

1. JS function in apsx:

   function DisableSave(){
         saveButton = document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>'); 
         saveButton.disabled=true;
         return false;
       }
2. Button script:

   <---asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnCommand="Button_Command" CommandName="Save" runat="server"
    Text="Save" OnClientClick="javascript:DisableSave();"/>
3. In code behind function Save()(supposed called by CommandName), set Save button enable back.

But When I run the code, only disable the save button, Code behind call did not happened.

How to fix it?

Comment: Even I remove return false; still get same result, no code behind call. IE/FF same result.

Comment: Hi guys, my button is inside UpdatePanel for partial update. Something looks like not as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently some browsers (IE) won't process the submit action of a button if it's disabled. I tried this in Firefox and it did postback, but no luck with IE.  One workaround, though not providing user feedback, would be to do  `OnClientClick="this.onclick= function() { return false; }"`. That will atleast prevent more postbacks from happening.

EDIT: onclick needed to be a function not a string.

Comment: this would completely stop post back. Can't call the code behind function.

Comment: This won't stop the postback from happening the first time. It will prevent the browser from posting back any MORE times though if the user starts clicking like crazy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that disabling the button using JavaScript in the onclick event stops the postback from occurring.

A simple workaround is illustrated in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DisableSubmitButton.aspx) CodeProject article.